# Oauth2.0 and user registration and sign in

Tags: oauth-2.0

If I need to get a user to sign up on my website I can use oauth2.0 to get the email address etc and I can obtain an access token for further calls to the Resource Server. My question is that once I have got e.g. user's email and name from the Resource Server how do I register the user on my website? and when user makes subsequent calls to my website how do I recognize that its the same user?

Answer (score 1):

The email and name on Authorization Server may be changed by user, but the user's id is not.
You can get user's id by getting `sub` field from Authorization Server to create a record of user on your database. For example saving in database like:

```
sub: string <-- user id on google
provider: google <--- the provider (Authorization Server)
```

-> every time user login by google, you can check if user is exists in your database by checking (sub, provider)

Where you can get `sub`?

- using access token to get userinfo endpoint of openid connect, OR
- validating and extracting id_token
  For example: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#obtainuserinfo

Comment: ok thanks, but what about creating a user session on my website for subsequent requests. once I have the user id and I have put that into my database, what is the general or the best practice to create a user session on my website.